# Python getting keyboardinterrupt error for time.sleep

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

I am calling a function successively 4 times in my python script but with different parameters:

```
testName = 'felb_ncq'
print "************ Test 1 %s ******************\n" % testName
tc.run_drivemaster_regression(testName)
time.sleep(30)

testName = 'felb_nonncq'
print "************ Test 2 %s ******************\n" % testName
tc.run_drivemaster_regression(testName)
time.sleep(30)

testName = 'be_sink_non_ncq'
print "************ Test 3 %s ******************\n" % testName
tc.run_drivemaster_regression(testName)
time.sleep(30)
```

The first pass or iteration goes fine, but in the second function call I am getting the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Neptune_Step_2015\Tests\SVTestcases\TC-Regression\drivemaster_regression.py", line 48, in <module>
time.sleep(30)
KeyboardInterrupt
```

Why I am getting a keyboardinterrupt error when I am not at all interrupting the execution?

One observation is: Instead of calling the function 4 times, if I run four different scripts, with individual parameters, then I all four passes run good. So, there must be some issue (like a race condition) while calling them successively in the same script.

Comment: Funny, I tried your code, but without `tc.run_drivemaster_regression(testName)`, it runs for me. Could you a bit elaborate what is `run_drivemaster_regression(testName)`?

Comment: Either your OS is buggy, your Python install is buggy, or the function is leaving a time bomb.  Try doing successive sleeps without a function call.

Comment: I also see this behavior on `macOs Mojave` with `python 3.7`

Answer (score 0):

The error you're seeing (KeyboardInterrupt) occurs when you interrupt the execution of your script using Ctrl+C. This is expected behavior, and it indicates that the script was terminated manually.

If you want to handle the KeyboardInterrupt exception gracefully and avoid displaying the traceback when the script is interrupted, you can catch the KeyboardInterrupt exception and exit the script cleanly.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gafao.png)

Comment: Please include your code as [text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) **NOT** as a [screenshot](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors).